# How can a buffer be duplicated in Vim?

Tags: vim, copy, buffer

I'm looking for a way to make a new buffer which is a copy of the current buffer.

I could then do something like the following to duplicate the current tab to a new tab in gVim for example:

```
:let b = bufnr("%") | tabnew | execute 'buffer' b | *duplicate*
```

However, this question isn't specific to tabs or gVim; I may want to duplicate the buffer after a `split` command or a `vert diffsplit` command. (Actually, `vert diffsplit` was the first instance that I realised I wanted to duplicate buffers.)

Ideally I also want to retain as much of the original buffer and window state as possible, including cursor position, with the exception that the original buffer read-only state is disregarded and the new buffer is always writeable.

Currently when I encounter this task, I type `ggyG`, open or move to the new buffer, then type `Vp`, but not only do I loose my cursor position for the new window, the copy command I use necessitates loosing the position in the original window as well. The process can surely be streamlined into a single command.

Answer (score 2):

The following sequence of commands should provide a good starting point…

1. in the original buffer:

   ```
   :%y
   :let my_view = winsaveview()
   :let my_ft = &filetype
   :new
   ```
2. in the new buffer:

   ```
   :execute "setf " . my_ft
   :0put
   :call winrestview(my_view)
   ```

Note that the "state" you want to duplicate is not buffer-specific but window-specific.

Comment: :0put leaves an empty line at bottom. How can we avoid this?

Comment: You can do `:$d` after `:0put`.

Answer (score 2):

My [clone plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4896) provides a `:CloneAs {file}` command for this. It basically creates a new buffer and copies over the original buffer, cursor position, and crucial options.